# Products in the draft category appear

Tags: php

It appears in the products in the draft category in the search. How can I do so that the products in the draft category do not appear.I am sharing the function code right at the bottom . draft is not a category name. category status

```
    public static function searchByCategoryByName($merchant_id='',$category_name='')
{
    $db = new DbExt();
    if($merchant_id>0 && !empty($category_name)){       
        
        $and='';
        $todays_day = date("l");
        $todays_day = !empty($todays_day)?strtolower($todays_day):'';                        
        $enabled_category_sked = getOption($merchant_id,'enabled_category_sked'); 
        if($enabled_category_sked==1){
            $and .= " AND $todays_day='1' ";
        }                   
        
        $stmt="
        SELECT 
        cat_id,
        merchant_id,
        category_name,
        category_description,
        photo,
        status,
        category_name_trans,
        category_description_trans          
        FROM {{category}}
        WHERE merchant_id = ".FunctionsV3::q($merchant_id)."                
        $and        
        AND status in ('publish')
        AND ( category_name like ".FunctionsV3::q( "%$category_name%" )." OR 
        category_description LIKE ".FunctionsV3::q( "%$category_name%" )."  )           
        ORDER BY category_name ASC
        ";                              
        if($res = $db->rst($stmt)){
            return $res;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that "draft" would be a category name? You just add a clause in the `WHERE` section? (like `category_name <> "draft"`)

Comment: not a category name. draft item status

Comment: so change it to `status <> "draft"` ?

Comment: I did not fully understand